# How do I fix fix error in plotting due to indexing?

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, indexing

```
import numpy as np
from pcw import dls
n = 5
alpha = np.logspace(-1, -5, n)
x = 0.5/alpha
uw = np.logspace(-9, 1)
t = 0.25/uw

for i in range(len(x)):      
    s = 2*np.array(dls([x[i]],t)) ###may be error is here due to index or something

    print(s)
    fontsize_labels = 12
    fontsize_tick_labels = 12
    fontsize_legend = 10
    
    fig = plt.figure()
        
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    
    color_list = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
    
    
    ax1.loglog(uw, s, linewidth=2, color=color_list[1], clip_on=True)
    
    
    ax1.set_xlabel(r'$u_{w}$', fontsize=fontsize_labels)    
    ax1.set_ylabel(r'$s_{w}\ /\ (Q/4 \pi T)$', fontsize=fontsize_labels)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=fontsize_tick_labels)
    ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
    ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')    
                   
    ax1.set_ylim(1e-4, 1e2)
    ax1.set_xlim(1e-9, 1e1)
    ax1.legend(frameon=False, loc='best', fontsize=fontsize_legend)
    # plt.tight_layout()        
    plt.show()
```

Hi All,
I am a very beginner in Python. After running this code, I am expecting to get five curves in a single plot but I am getting five different plots. Please suggest to me how to get over this error. The error may be near for loop as per my knowledge. Your help will be highly appreciated.

@Diziet Asahi I want all five curves on the same axes.

Comment: Do you want 5 curves on the same axes, or 5 subplots with one curve each ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the figure and axes creation outside of your loop:

```py
fig = plt.figure()        
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(len(x)):      
    (...)
    ax1.loglog(uw, s, linewidth=2, color=color_list[1], clip_on=True)
    (...)
plt.show()
```

Comment: One more help please! All curves are of same color now. How to make them different?

Comment: change `color=color_list[1]` to `color=color_list[i]`. In general, you should take everything that's constant (does not depend on `i`) out of your loop

Comment: Thanks a lot.....I am really grateful to you for helping so quickly and in a nice way.

Comment: Is it possible to put the legend automatically (not manually by defining x and y location using "ax.text") for all five curves? From top to bottom the curves are for alpha=0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001 & 0.000001 (one for each). Please suggest any answer. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Please consult the matplotlib tutorials https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html, and the documentation https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend